# Glcient sync fails

Tags: git, flutter, github, dart, chromium

I am following this https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Setting-up-the-Engine-development-environment

On step 5, I get this error

```
c:\Flutter\engine>gclient sync
1>________ running 'git -c core.deltaBaseCacheLimit=2g clone --no-checkout --progress git@github.com:tolotrasamuel/engine.git C:\Flutter\engine\src\_gclient_flutter_c4ifc5wl' in 'C:\Flutter\engine'
1>Cloning into 'C:\Flutter\engine\src\_gclient_flutter_c4ifc5wl'...
1>fatal: Could not read from remote repository..r IP address '140.82.121.4' to the list of known hosts.
1>Please make sure you have the correct access rights
1>and the repository exists.
1>WARNING: subprocess '"git" "-c" "core.deltaBaseCacheLimit=2g" "clone" "--no-checkout" "--progress" "git@github.com:tolotrasamuel/engine.git" "C:\Flutter\engine\src\_gclient_flutter_c4ifc5wl"' in C:\Flutter\engine failed; will retry after a short nap...
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Change the URL in `.gclient` file form step 4 to

```
"url": "https://github.com/YOURGITHUBNAME/engine.git"
```

Answer (score 0):

I too encountered this issue.
This seems bad combination of Ubuntu 20 and Chromium.

This is because of very large commit histories of chromium it required too much size and ubuntu 20 doesn't support this much.

So to get android chromium in ubuntu20 you need to follow the below steps:

**fetch --nohooks --no-history android**

**gclient sync -D --no-history**

once this is done trigger your build command.
Without patch history git pack size will not exceed 2GB limit and it will work fine same as older systems.

Comment: can you help with my issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74514069/error-command-git-c-core-deltabasecachelimit-2g-fetch-origin-prune-returne